# Need a transistor to drive 12v 400mA Solenoid

Tags: transistors, solenoid, controller

I need a transistor whose base will be driven by a controller (3mA max base current).
the Vce(sat) should be less than 0.5 or max 0.7. And collector current required by solenoid is 400mA. I am unable to find a transistor with such specification.
can you suggest any? single or darlington is also ok

Comment: what is the time of operation? is it short periods of for long periods of time with 400ma constantly being pumped through the transistor?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sziklai_pair

Comment: are you doing parts selection? you looking for surface mount components? or through hole? what is your budget? are you good at soldering? could a very low power NPN transistor turn on a 12V biased MOSFET (a really good option by the way) ?

Comment: hi, i want SMD component..and ya , i want to select only transistor with the given specification

Comment: its a door lock application in which the solenoid will be used to open n close the door...

Comment: sorry the max base current should be 3mA max, i have corrected it in the question now.

Comment: The best questions are ones where you describe the problem and allow people to suggest answers.  Perhaps edit your question to be less specific and talk about what you are trying to do, rather than how you will solve it.

Comment: @Priyanka did you want NPN or PNP?

Comment: Please don't type like a chat-man and use capital word when use "I" for refer to yourself. thanks

Comment: Any configuration is ok, but I need SMD coponent, should be able to produce Ic of around 400mA with 3mA of base current

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With a distinct lack of detail, I shall prescribe this component:

http://www.digikey.com.au/product-detail/en/MMBT123S-7-F/MMBT123S-FDICT-ND/815722

This is a surface mount NPN transistor. It has a beta value of 140-150, at 400ma load. Your 3ma max will drive 400ma through it. It will dissipate ~100mW through it during this time, but it is rated to 300mW.

do NOT put >5V into it's base pin. The max Collect-Emitter voltage is 18V, so respect that too.

dont forget a simple barrier/rectifier diode (1N4001 or whatever) parallel to your solonoid

Comment: yes , the controller pin will output 3.3v as high..so no problem with it...

Comment: okay, so 1k Ohm resistor will give you the 3mA from 3.3V. nice work! good luck. if you agree, please vote as answer whenever you like.

Comment: hi, in the datasheet of mmbt123S the gain of the transistor in saturation mode is 10 (i.e Ic=300mA, Ib=30mA). so for 3mA of Ib how it wil give 400mA? gain should be higher, right? correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: @Priyanka  not sure what you mean, where on the datasheet does it say that? Please see Fig. 2, "Typical DC Current Gain vs
Collector Current" And follow it to 0.4A and up to the gain, its between 100 and 150.  Remember, Ic = Beta * Ib

Comment: see, i want to use this transistor as a switch , that is , it will be used in saturation mode , so my question what will be the gain when it will be in saturation?

Comment: if you look at figure 4, Vce will be ~115mV when collector current is 400mA. The Beta value will be closer to 200 when at 400mA. With only those charts, it's hard to say - but I'm pretty damn sure it will work! not sure if "Trust me, i'm an Engineer" is good enough though. Let me try to prove that it will work.. I'm trying to find a SPICE model for you

Comment: ya i am waiting ..

Comment: I have never used Vce or bothered about saturation when i've used transistors (as switching, and power switch). I think you confuse the saturation point with something else - driving maximum base current is not what you want. If you only put 3mA into the base, it will NOT be in saturation region, and you WILL get an HFE value (Beta value) of 150-200 maximum, according to the given charts in the datasheet. I suggest you read this page:
http://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/transistor/tran_4.html

and see that you are not putting anywhere near enough current to be saturation mode.

Comment: anyway that device at full saturation has max 0.5V as you've specified. Maybe this just isnt good enough? maybe you need a Darlington driver or set up a Sziklai pair using two of the transistors that i've suggested?

Comment: yes you are right , so i think the transistor which you mmentioned should worrk fine..

Comment: darlingtone driver ? means i will have to use 2 MMBT123s?

Comment: yeah, but that means you could sink 2-3A with only 1mA. ignore that, that is more for motor driving and other larger current applications (or much lower current from your controller, if you were limitd to 0.5 mA or 1mA then maybe you would need a low Beta Darlington driver )

Comment: can u suggest a darlington driver? but Vce(sat) should be less that 0.7v. I have read that for darlington pair the Vce(sat) value is much higher..like 2 volts.

Comment: its just double the diode drop, rather than one. Look at the Sziklai pair for <1 VCE as you wanted. 

you do not need a darlington pair, OR a sziklai pair. I suggest you try one of those devices I have shown you, first. just change up the gate resistor until your load current is perfect! Remember that temperature may affect it, so long term current loads may cause a current run-away event :D